# Declare @ variable in SQL returning an error

Tags: mysql, sql, variable-declaration

I am trying to declare a variable in SQL. I Have tried both

```
declare @mean INT;
set @mean = .5;
```

and

```
declare @mean INT
set @mean = .5
```

I keep getting this error:

> An unexpected token "" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "declare @mean INT"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to declare your variable as a loosely-typed user-defined variables are defined using '@', you can simply go:

```
SET @mean := .5
```

If not, then perhaps you want to define a variable in a stored procedure, then you can perhaps define as follows:

```
DECLARE  mean INT;
SET mean = .5;      // not sure you mean INT here though?
```

You may find this [SO link useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference) for describing the differences in my sql variables. Also check out the mysql manual([user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)) / ([local variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html)).

I think some of the confusion here may stem from the differing syntax that T-SQL uses from Mysql, but read the above link and use whatever method suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in a stored procedure, you don't need the @ for a local variable.
If this is just a session variable you are trying to create, you don't need a `DECLARE`; just `SET @mean := 5;`

*I'm not positive, but I think DECLARE may not even be valid outside of stored procedures.*