# How to set values of variable using SET in MySql?

Tags: mysql

How to set values to variable using `SET` in `MySql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare the [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html), you can just `SET` them as you have in your question. 
Once variable is set you can refer to it in SELECT or other statements, for example:

```
SELECT @_achat_loc;

+-------------+
| @_achat_loc |
+-------------+
| achat       |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

or

```
UPDATE a SET b=@_achat_loc;
```

Comment: But is it correct how i have set to set values using SET ?

Comment: @Mayur, yes, see here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference

Comment: Ok i am confused that where to use double Quot Single Quot or no Quot ?

Comment: You need to use single quotes if ANSI_QUOTES has been enabled. See here for more information regarding the quotes: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks