# MYSQL/JDBC: Run multiple statements in a single query throwing the error: error in SQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc

When i have multiple statements in my MySQL query, it is giving me the error: SQLException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server.

Here is my query:

```
SET @loner_900_id = 1722;
SELECT ds.device_id AS deviceID, dsl.* 
FROM devices_statuses AS ds 
INNER JOIN devices_statuses_location AS dsl ON ds.id = dsl.device_status_id 
WHERE ds.device_id IN (@loner_900_id);
```

In this query if i remove the `SET @loner_900_id = 1722;` and replace the variable `@loner_900_id` with the value `1722`, then it works without a problem. But, i would like to run with the `"SET @loner_900_id = 1722;"` statement. Please share your thoughts on this.

This is what i do to retrieve the data from the above query. I used JDBC connection.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://<HOST>/test?user=xyz&password=xyz&allowMultiQueries=true";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
conn.createStatement();
resultSet = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

The error is thrown on the line `"resultSet = st.executeQuery(sql);"`

Comment: most mysql drivers do NOT allow multiple statements in a single query() call. it's a basic defense against some forms of sql injection attack. You'll have to call query() multiple times: `query('set ...'); query('select ...');`

Comment: Also, when you set user-defined variable like this one, it should be `SET @variable := value`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference

Comment: @Marc, I can do that, but in that case, since each statement is run in a separate session, the 2nd query that i run, will not have any idea about the variable that i have set in my 1st statement. Right?

Comment: mysql vars are done on a per-connection basis. as long as you use the SAME connection for the two queries, things will "just work".

Comment: @kittykittybangbang, i agree on your syntax. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a `PreparedStatement` instead and its `setInt` instead?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks for the suggestion. Will give that a try.