# MySQL Insert after trigger clarification

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code here:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger 
AFTER INSERT ON users
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @uid VARCHAR(60)
    SET @uid = (SELECT userid FROM inserted)
    INSERT INTO user_locations (id,uid,lat,lng) VALUES (0,@uid,5.0,5.0)
END;
```

The idea is to insert generated user id into other table alongside some other data as soon as it hits the first 'users' table but phpMyAdmin gives this error code:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @uid VARCHAR(60)
SET @uid = (SELECT userid FROM inserted)
at line 3
```

Can someone clarify why this trigger is bad?

Comment: you are missing FOR EACH ROW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see four problems:

- You have to use `DELIMITER`s so that your able to finish the commands with a semicolon as usual.
- `FOR EACH ROW` is missing.
- Use `new.uid` to access the recently inserted uid.
- I'd also suggest using procedure variables instead of session-specific user-defined @variables, the latter ones being loosely typed and not declared as you've done.

But you don't even have to declare a variable. **If you don't use phpMyAdmin**:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger 
AFTER INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO user_locations (id,uid,lat,lng) VALUES (0,new.uid,5.0,5.0);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10259528/279610) about delimiter and [the MySQL 5.7 docs on triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010042/279610) about variables.

**Edit, I overread you're using phpMyAdmin:**

I don't use phpMyAdmin. But you can (stolen from [here](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Trigger))

- In phpMyAdmin, select the database that you want to work with.
- Go to the SQL tab at the top of the page.
- In the "Run SQL query/queries on database" form, change the Delimiter to $$. (Located in a small box at the bottom of the form)
- Enter your SQL trigger into the main dialog box on the form. The correct syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger 
AFTER INSERT ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO user_locations (id,uid,lat,lng) VALUES (0,new.uid,5.0,5.0);
END;$$
```

- Hit "GO" with Super privilege.