# How to use JOIN in UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE reputations SET 
    type = new.type,
    score = new.score,
    qora = NOT (new.post_id = (SELECT t1.id
        FROM qanda t1 
        WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM qanda t2 
            WHERE ID = new.post_id 
                AND t1.ID = t2.related)
                OR t1.id = new.post_id)
                AND Type = 0)),
    question_id = (SELECT t1.id
        FROM qanda t1 
        WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM qanda t2 
            WHERE ID = new.post_id 
                AND t1.ID = t2.related)
                OR t1.id = new.post_id)
                AND Type = 0),
    post_id = new.post_id,
    table_code = new.table_code,
    comment_id = new.comment_id,
    owner_id = new.author_id,
    date_time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE events_table_id = old.id;
```

All I'm trying to do is remove one of those sub-queries, since both are identical. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think your parentheses balance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff True ... I added one more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would `DECLARE` a local variable to store the result of the subquery. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-variables.html

Use the `SELECT...INTO` syntax to store the result of a query into a variable. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE QANDA_ID INT;

  SELECT t1.id FROM qanda t1 
  WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM qanda t2 WHERE ID = new.post_id AND t1.ID = t2.related)
    OR t1.id = new.post_id) AND Type = 0
  INTO QANDA_ID;

  UPDATE reputations SET ...
    qora = not (new.post_id = QANDA_ID),
    question_id = QANDA_ID,
    ...

END
```

I made the variable name in all caps just to make it stand out in this example. But you can name it anything you want, it follows the same rules as other identifier names.

However, I suggest you *don't* name local variables the same as any of the column names in the table you use in the UPDATE statement. It gets confusing if you do that.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote, just do you think which approach is better? either your *(using variable)* or Gordon's answer *(using `CROSS JOIN`)*? Noted that both work correctly.

Comment: Both work fine, so I'd choose the one that is more straightforward and easier to code.

Comment: Can you please tell my why you not used `@` in the beginning of the variable name? Actually I'm confused, when exactly should I use `@` for variables in MySQL?

Comment: @MartinAJ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you could use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
UPDATE reputations r CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT t1.id
        FROM qanda t1 
        WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM qanda t2 
                       WHERE ID = new.post_id and t1.ID = t2.related
                      ) OR
               t1.id = new.post_id
              ) AND
              Type = 0
       ) t1
    SET r.type = new.type,
        r.score = new.score,
        r.qora = not (new.post_id = t1.id),
        r.question_id = t1.id,
        r.post_id = new.post_id,
        r.table_code = new.table_code,
        r.comment_id = new.comment_id,
        r.owner_id = new.author_id,
        r.date_time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE r.events_table_id = old.id;
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote, just do you think which approach is better? either your *(using `CROSS JOIN`)* or Bill's answer *(using variable)*? Noted that both work correctly.

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . I prefer to keep code in a single query where possible.  Obviously, Bill has lots of valuable experience and good advice and his answers reflect that.  The two alternatives are both very reasonable.