# MySQL Stored Procedure LIKE syntaxt in Cursor Declaration

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am very green when it comes to MySQL Stored Procedures and i have been having trouble with selecting all payments received in the current month and looping through them to see which accounts did not pay the monthly fee, my problem seems to be with the LIKE statement in the declaration of the cursor. Here is the code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`wisper`@`%` PROCEDURE `process_rejections`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE cursor_ID INT(11);
    DECLARE account_id INT(11);
    DECLARE amount_paid DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE date_paid DATETIME;
    DECLARE cur_year INT DEFAULT (SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()));
    DECLARE cur_month INT DEFAULT (SELECT MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()));
    DECLARE comp_date VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT (SELECT CONCAT(cur_year,'-',cur_month));
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT `id`, `account_id`, `amount_paid`, `date` 
    FROM `payments_received` 
    WHERE `date`LIKE CONCAT('%',@comp_date,'%');

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cursor_i;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_i INTO cursor_ID, account_id, amount_paid, date_paid;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
            //Do Stuff here like change the status of the account
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_i;
END
```

IF i remove this:

```
WHERE `date` LIKE CONCAT('%',@comp_date,'%');
```

Everything works but it obviously selects * payments received instead of those that occured during ,for example, Aug 2017. I do not want to select * because over time there will be hundreds of thousands of rows in the specific table and i do not want the overhead to become too much. I have also tested this:

```
WHERE `date` LIKE '2017-08-11';
```

Which also does not work. During debuggin i also tried to use a specifi date like this:

```
WHERE `date` = '2017-08-11';
```

And everything worked nicely but it is obviously just to test and see if the WHERE cluase was syntactically correct inside the cursor declaration.

I am at a lost here and would appreciate some assistance from you guy's.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Life lesson: Avoid the sentence "does not work" when posting questions. If it would, you wouldn't be asking. Always post error messages instead or describe what is happening. There is no useful information in "does not work".

Comment: There isnt any errrors, it returns zero rows, which should not be the case.

Comment: The problem is the use of an undefined session variable... see my answer below.

Comment: That's why I also wrote "describe what is happening"

Comment: I totally get your username now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You've debugged your code well, and you've isolated the problem successfully.  It's not the `LIKE` itself, or the fact it is a stored procedure that's tripping you up.

**Problem**: You're using a session variable (the variable is prepended with an `@`), not the stored procedure variable declared a few lines earlier.

**Solution**: Drop the `@` (on `comp_date`):

```
WHERE `date` LIKE CONCAT('%', comp_date, '%');
```

Assuming the session variable isn't set, I believe you'll be getting `NULL`, which won't work.  Thus the symptom you're seeing.

There's some useful explanation on another SO question here: [MySQL: @variable vs. variable. Whats the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)

Comment: Thanks for your responce.

Comment: I have dropped the '@' but is still return zero rows. i think my problem lies with missing quotes in the LIKE, for instance '%2017-08%' works but i am struggling to concat them into the declaration. I have tried CONCAT("'%",comp_date,"%'") but it still return zero rows.

Comment: Can you try adding a simple `SELECT CONCAT('%',@comp_date,'%')` in the stored procedure to debug what value it returns? (You should get a second result set, which will be visible in your client.  Failing that, do a `SELECT CONCAT('%',@comp_date,'%') INTO @debug` and then call `SELECT @debug;` after the stored proc runs.)

Comment: I'm comfortable the mechanism you're using (as originally described) should work given my own tests:  `> SELECT created_at FROM customers WHERE created_at LIKE CONCAT('%2017-08%');` returns `| 2017-08-09 21:48:41 |`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, turns out the comp_date looks like this 2017-8 instead of using leading zeros like this 2017-08, here is the finished code:

PS: Yes i feel like an idiot for not testing the values that i submit in the statement, but maybe someone else also struggles with it and this can help them.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`wesley`@`%` PROCEDURE `process_rejections`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE cursor_ID INT(11);
    DECLARE account_id INT(11);
    DECLARE amount_paid DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE date_paid DATETIME;

    DECLARE comp_date VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT 
    CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()), '-', LPAD(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()), 2, '0'));

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR 
    FOR SELECT `id`, `account_id`, `amount_paid`, `date` 
    FROM `payments_received` 
    WHERE `date` 
    LIKE CONCAT('%', comp_date,'%');

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cursor_i;
    read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO cursor_ID, account_id, amount_paid, date_paid;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
        //Do stuff here like changing account status
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_i;
END
```

Note how i declare comp_date to account for leading zeros.