# How to set a variable for (select * from) in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to set a variable for x.* and y.* like this:

```
("SELECT x.* as x_var, y.* as y_var 
  FROM table_x x 
  INNER JOIN table_y y on x.id = y.id WHERE x.id='1'");
```

But the code gives an error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as table_x, y.* as y_var FROM table_x x INNER JOIN table_y d ON x.id = y.id WH' at line 1

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to set aliases one-by-one; `* as` doesn't make sense.

Comment: like u.id as uid, y.something as y_smt etc?

Comment: The error is expected behavior given the malformed SQL syntax. I strongly recommend that we ditch the `*` placeholder in the SELECT list, and explicitly list the columns to be returned. Each individual expression (column) in the SELECT list can be assigned an alias.  `SELECT x.var AS exvar, x.foo AS exdotfoo, y.bar as wydottbar ...`

Comment: Thank you, so there's no other ways to name the x.* right?
The only way is to is giving names for each column such like >x.foo as xbar

Answer (score 0):

With respect, your use of "variable" is ambiguous. Please read this: [MySQL: @variable vs. variable. What's the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)

If you mean column aliases, you do

```
 SELECT col1 a, col2 b, col3 c
   FROM whatever
```

You tried to assign multiple aliases with `SELECT * AS alias`. You Can't Do That™.

If you mean local variables you want

```
 SELECT @a := col1, @b := col1
```

And, you can't do `SELECT @a: = *` either.

**Pro tip:** Avoid using `SELECT *` whenever you can. Instead give a list of column names you want.