# Use function stuff for xml path in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query and I want to use MySQL but I don't know about using the MySQL function

**MyQuery**

```
declare @query  as varchar(max)
declare @data  as varchar(max)

set @query =  STUFF((select ','+column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_TestStockClaris' and ORDINAL_POSITION >= 4
for xml path('')),1,1,'')

set @data = 'select top 10 kodescala,'+@query+' from tbl_TestStockClaris'

execute(@data);
```

Comment: Did you tried group_concat() in MySQL? this is the equivalent of STUFF in MSSQL.

Comment: mysql is very different to sqlserver in many ways, Apart from not having stuff you cannot DECLARE user defined varaibles (@varables) or EXECUTE sql statements or run code like this outside a stored program in mysq or use + as a concat shortcut. And that's just the differences in your few lines of published code.

Comment: @P.Salmon for the stuff function, it has successfully used group_concat, is there an idea for storing excute variables like procedure?

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: @P.Salmon;    how to execute the data variable value and the data value is saved to the query..

my query. 
set data = ('select group_concat(column_name) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = "tbl_TestStockClaris" and ORDINAL_POSITION >= 4');

PREPARE query FROM concat('select data from tbl_TestStockClaris');

EXECUTE query ;

Comment: Please edit your question to include the entire stored program you have created including the delimiters , if you are not using a stored program then you have to use a user defined variable to build your sql statement see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference/1010042. Can you provide the table definition as text in the question?

Answer (score 0):

treat your sql query variable as string.

```
declare @query  as varchar(max)
declare @data  as varchar(max)

set @query =  'STUFF((select '',''+column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN 
where TABLE_NAME = ''kodescala'' and ORDINAL_POSITION >= 4
for xml path('''')),1,1,'''')';

set @data ='select top 10 kodescala,'+@query+' from tbl_TestStockClaris';

execute(@data);
```

Comment: My query is running on sql server but I just want to use mysql but I don't know the mysql function

Answer (score 0):

an example of a prepared statement

```
set @data = (select 
                 concat('select ' , gc, ' from dates limit 10;')
                from
                (select group_concat(column_name) gc from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'dates') s

                ); 

select @data;
PREPARE query from @data; 
EXECUTE query ;
deallocate prepare query;
```