# Execute sql using a stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following stored procedure. The idea is to get a list of databases and execute an sql statement.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE updateMySQL (
    IN  theSQL varchar(4000)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE theDatabases varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

    -- declare cursor for employee email
    DEClARE curDatabase 
        CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata where SCHEMA_NAME = 'mydb' order by 1;

    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN curDatabase;

    getDatabase: LOOP
        FETCH curDatabase INTO theDatabases;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getDatabase;
        END IF;
        -- build email list
      -- SET emailList = CONCAT(theDatabases,";",emailList);
        SET @sql:=CONCAT('USE ',@curDatabase);
        PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @SQL;
        EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
        
        PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @theSQL;
        EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
        
        
    END LOOP getDatabase;
    CLOSE curDatabase;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am attempting to execute the stored procedure like this,

```
SET @theSQL = 'ALTER VIEW `Reports` AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        `tableA`.`Id` AS `Id`,
        `tableA`.`letterId` AS `letterId`
    FROM
        `mytable` `tableA`
    ORDER BY 1';

call updateMySQL(@theSQL);
```

**EDIT** There was an error on executing the procedure,
***Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1***

I am using **mysql 8.0.17**

Comment: I don't quite get this SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata where SCHEMA_NAME = 'mydb' order by 1;  - will only return 1 row

Comment: @P.Salmon SCHEMA_NAME = 'mydb'  will be specific to your database. So you can put your database name in place of 'mydb' and try again

Comment: This alters nothing - query returns ONE row always, because database names must be (and respectively they are) unique. I.e. you simply execute your query on specific database which is hardcoded in SP.

Comment: It returns one row but that should not stop it from executing the sql. I can always put " like 'mydb%'  ". It should still be able to execute the sql passed as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this part

```
    SET @sql:=CONCAT('USE ',@curDatabase);
    PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
    
    PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @theSQL;
    EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
```

to this:

```
    SET @sql:=CONCAT('USE ',@curDatabase);
    PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement; /* don't forget to deallocate */
    
    /* there's a difference between the variables @theSQL and theSQL (your parameter) */
    /* IIRC prepare statements need user defined variables or a syntax error occurs. Therefore I simply assign the parameter to a user-defined variable */
    SET @theSQL = theSQL;
    PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @theSQL;
    EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

Read more about user-defined variables here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html
Here the differences are explained: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010042/447489
When you don't initialize them, their content is just `NULL`. Since there's a difference between user-defined variables and local variables (and also your parameter variable), your current solution did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Investigate carefully [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  SQL Statements  /  Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html), the section "SQL Syntax Allowed in Prepared Statements".

This section claims FULL list of statements which are allowed in Prepared statements. `ALTER VIEW` is **NOT** listed. So it is **NOT** allowed.

Use `DROP VIEW` and `CREATE VIEW` instead.

Always receive and investigate all error messages.

Comment: I changed my stored procedure to drop the view but I am getting an error. I hadn't noticed the error previously but it is the same error when the procedure had ' ALTER VIEW'. I have edited my question with the error message

Comment: @Bisoux Now pay attention - error message refers to `'NULL'` whereas your SQL text (either SP and query) does not contain this substring.

Comment: @Bisoux I have covered this in my answer. Also note, that multiple statements in a prepared statement are not allowed. Instead of dropping and creating the view, you can do `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_name AS SELECT ...`