# Cannot rollback user-defined variables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, session-variables, user-defined-variables

First, I set `John` to the [user-defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) `@name` as shown below:

```sql
SET @name = 'John';
```

Then, I set `David` to `@name` in a transaction, then rollbacked as shown below:

```sql
BEGIN;
SET @name = 'David';
ROLLBACK;
```

But, `@name` was not rollbacked to `John` as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT @name;
+-------+
| @name |
+-------+
| David |
+-------+
```

I read the doc about [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) and [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) but I could not find any relevant information.

So, how can I rollback user-defined variables?

Comment: Transactions effects only the tables whose engine is transactional. None other objects, including user-defined variables, are saved by transactional savepoints.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A user-defined variable is as long active as long the session is online and disappear, when you disconnect. It has a session scope

A transaction scope don't touch that and can't influence it, besides setting the value and it will not reverse it as it is putside of its scope