# A local variable is not rollbacked in a MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, rollback, local-variables

I'm trying to rollback the local variable `v1` from `5` to `2` with [ROLLBACK statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) in `my_proc()` procedure but `v1` is not rollbacked keeping `5` as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc() 
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 2; -- v1 is 2
  START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT 5 INTO v1;       -- v1 is 5
    SELECT v1; -- v1 is 5
    ROLLBACK;  -- Here
    SELECT v1; -- v1 is 5
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

This below is the actuall result which `v1` is not rollbacked keeping `5`:

```sql
mysql> CALL my_proc();
+------+
| v1   |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------+
| v1   |
+------+
|    5 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, how can I rollback the local variable?

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of the question you asked 2 days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663486/cannot-rollback-user-defined-variables-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Rollback rolls back a database transaction, cancelling out any changes it did **to the data in the tables**. Changing a variable's value is not saved in a mysql table, therefore rollback does no roll changes back to variables.

The only workaround is to keep the variable's original value and restore it if certain conditions are met.